# How to make `^I` displayed as 4 blank whites?

Tags: vim

I have set tab key as 4 blank white in my vim configuration.

```
set tabstop=4
set sts=4
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

Why so many `^I` when to open files?
How to make ^I displayed as 4 blank whites?
I want to keep `$` displayed in vim console,`set nolist` will make `^I` and `$` all dispeared.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many others have said, you have `list` turned on.  This option displays whitespace characters as visible characters.  The default display for tabs is "^I".  You're seeing a lot of "^I" characters because you're working with a file with mixed indentation.

You have two ways you can go about fixing this:

1. Fix the indentation to be what you expect.  You can do this with `:retab`.
2. Ignore the fact that there are tabs and continue to mix indentation (boo!).  You can configure vim to display tabs as blank spaces by running `:set listchars+=tab:\ \`.  That's <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:retab` to convert existing tabs into spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You have `set list`, if you do not want this just run `set nolist`. You can also change the list chars with:

```
set listchars+=tab:\|\
```

which will show a `|` followed by `tabstop - 1` spaces for each tab

Answer (score 1):

The list option shows tabs and EOLs.  Try this:

:set nolist

Or get rid of :set list